# How can I make the options on the `Listview` navigate me to the correct fragments based on what is typed on the `Searchview`?

Tags: android, kotlin, searchview

I am unable to navigate to the next fragment when there are characters typed in the `searchview`. For instance if I were to type 'Dog' in the `searchview` and select the `Dog` option from the `Listview` it would direct me back to the `Homepage`.

However if nothing is in the `searchview`, as in nothing is typed out in the `searchview` the navigation works fine. For instance, clicking on the Dog option from the `Listview` would navigate me to the Dog fragment.

I also can't seem to get the listview to collapse when not clicking on the `searchview`.

I have attached an image as a reference to the problem I am facing.

In the code below I am using a default `ArrayAdapter`

[Image Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxRsE.png)

**Searchview.kt**

```
//searchview
    var user = arrayOf("Home","Dog","Cat","Hamster")


    adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, user)

    binding.categories.adapter = adapter
    binding.searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
            if (user.contains(query)) {
                adapter.filter.filter(query)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "No Match found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            return false
        }
        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
            adapter.filter.filter(newText)
            return false
        }
    })
    val home = adapter.getItemId(0)
    val cat = adapter.getItemId(1)
    val hamster = adapter.getItemId(2)
    val dog = adapter.getItemId(3)
    binding.categories.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, ID ->
        when(ID){
            home ->{navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_home2)
            }
            cat -> {navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_cat) }
            hamster -> {navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_hamster)}
            dog -> {navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_dog)
            }
        }
    }
```

**Searchview.xml**

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
.....       

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:queryHint="Enter Search"
        android:background="@drawable/searchview_background"
        app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        app:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"


        >
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView>
    <!--Listview-->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/categories"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/searchview_listitem"/>
     
.....

<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `getItemId` does for an `ArrayAdapter` is return the item's *position* in the displayed list - you can check the source [on this extremely nice site](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java;bpv=1;bpt=1;l=409?gsn=getItemId&gs=kythe%3A%2F%2Fandroid.googlesource.com%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject%3Flang%3Djava%3Fpath%3Dandroid.widget.ArrayAdapter%23499309ad7c72675cdb0ebc8db4989b8a3ecc45283c13b5ddccad6ef3d4b8eafd):

> ```
> @Override
> public long getItemId(int position) {
>     return position;
> }
> ```

It has use for other adapter implementations (e.g. where the ID is the database row the item corresponds to) but not in this case.

So because you're taking your original list, and storing their *positions* as `home`, `cat` etc., your click listener actually ends up equivalent to this:

```
when(position){
    0 -> navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_home2)
    1 -> navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_cat)
    2 -> navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_hamster)
    3 -> navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_dog)
}
```

And `position` relates to their position *in the displayed list*, not in your data set. So when you filter on *"dog"*, and *Dog* is the only item displayed, its `position` is **0**. Click that, and its ID (which is *position* remember) matches the first branch, the one that takes you to *home*.

---

So you can't really rely on the `position` or default `getItemId` implementation (which is the same thing) to identify your actual items. The easiest fix would be to grab the item itself (a `String` in this case) and compare to that:

```
when(adapter.getItem(position)){
    "Home" -> navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_home2)
    "Cat" -> navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_cat)
    "Hamster" -> navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_hamster)
    "Dog" -> navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_dog)
}
```

Or if you really want to use indices, you could look up the item in your source array

```
val dataSet = user
// or you could create a list/array from inside the adapter with
// val dataSet = (0 until count).map(this::getItem)

when(dataSet.indexOf(adapter.getItem(position)){
    0 -> navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_home2)
    1 -> navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_cat)
    2 -> navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_hamster)
    3 -> navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_dog)
}
```

---

But this is kinda brittle - it requires you to define the order of your data in two different places, the ordering in the original array, and the ordering in your `when` matcher. (You've already hit that problem - *dog* and *hamster* are in the wrong place in the `when`!). Using the String values ensures you match the correct item - unless you make a typo, or change the text in the original array but not the matcher. They're separate, unconnected values, so there's no protection against that. It could break easily.

It would be better to associate your items with a label *and* a destination *together*, at the point where you define your data. Since `ArrayAdapter` gets the string it displays by calling `toString()` on whatever objects your array contains, you can put anything in there! You could make a simple class:

```
class Item(val name: String, val destination: Int) {
    // we only want to display the name
    override fun toString() = name
}
```

then use that to define your data all in the same place:

```
val items = arrayOf(
    Item("Home", R.id.action_global_home2),
    Item("Cat", R.id.action_global_cat),
    Item("Hamster", R.id.action_global_hamster),
    Item("Dog", R.id.action_global_dog)
)
adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items)
```

Then to handle your click, you just need to grab the `Item` for the clicked *position*, and it has its navigation action right there in the data!

```
binding.categories.setOnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _ ->
    val item = adapter.getItem(position)
    item?.let { navController.navigate(it.destination) }
    // or item?.destination?.run(navController::navigate) - same thing!
}
```

You could do all this in an `enum class` since it's hardcoded, but this way allows you to create arbitrary `Item`s, load your data from a database or the internet etc, which is probably what you want to do in the end anyway. And you can put whatever data you want in `Item`, whatever's useful!